# Using read() in cakephp to retrieve row with array of data

Tags: cakephp, model

I want to know if it is possible to retrieve a row from the database using something similar to the following:

```
    if (!empty($this->params['form'])) {
        $place = array();
        $place['city'] = $this->params['form']['city'];
        $place['area'] = $this->params['form']['state'];
        $place['country'] = $this->params['form']['country'];
        $place['iso'] = $this->params['form']['iso'];

        $this->Place->set($place);
        $place_found = $this->Place->read();
    }
```

Is there some way I can preset the data in the Place model using the array and then use Place read. I'm looking for something simple like the usual:

```
$this->Place->id = 7;
$place_found = $this->Place->Read();
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
$this->Place->city = blah;
$this->Place->area = foo; etc....

$place_found = $this->Place->read();
```

However, that also does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't you ever used [`find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find)?! [`read()`](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelread) only fetches a row with the ID passed.

```
$place_found = $this->Place->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
          'Place.city' => $city,
          'Place.area' => $area
          // etc
     )
));
```

If you need to build the conditions manually you can create a conditions array to pass like so:

```
$placeConditions = array();
$placeConditions['city'] = $city;
if($area) {
    $placeConditions['area'] = $area;
}

$places = $this->Place->find('first', array('conditions' => $placeConditions));
```

I suggest you read the page I linked, you will soon find out there is never a reason to use the `read()` method.

Comment: I am looking for an easier way to do this by using the array without having to write everything out in full. I am trying to find out if cake has an easier way to do this. You will notice if you use $this->Place->set($place) it actually set the Place->data to the value provided, I'm pretty sure there exists a method to then retrieve the missing values but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: Please see updated answer, `read()` can only retrieve rows based on an ID.

Comment: Have to agree with Dunhamzzz. The analog for doing a `SELECT` query with conditions in a `WHERE` clause is to use `find()`. Consider `read()` a special case that only queries by ID and automatically populates the model instead of returning an array.

Comment: This is probably a misconception on my part, looking at this again today and looking at your answer they are essentially the same amount of coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In model you could do:

```
$this->id = 3; //place id
$this->Place->read();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't have the id available, I am trying to find based on other conditions

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is what you're looking for(with your code):

```
if (!empty($this->params['form'])) {
    $place = array();
    $place['city'] = $this->params['form']['city'];
    $place['area'] = $this->params['form']['state'];
    $place['country'] = $this->params['form']['country'];
    $place['iso'] = $this->params['form']['iso'];

    //$this->Place->set($place); //don't need it here I think
    $place_found = $this->Place->find('all',array('conditions'=>$place));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use "find()", not "read()", but - it's almost as simple as your example code and should work.  (also, there's a shortcut for the array_push() I believe, but - I like to use this for readability - personal preference):

```
if (!empty($this->params['form'])) {
    $conditions = array();
    array_push($conditions, array('Place.city' => $this->params['form']['city']);
    array_push($conditions, array('Place.state' => $this->params['form']['state']);
    array_push($conditions, array('Place.country' => $this->params['form']['country']);
    array_push($conditions, array('Place.iso' => $this->params['form']['iso']);

    $this->Place->set($place);
    $place_found = $this->Place->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
}
```